What battery connector is this and how to disconnect?

This is the battery connector of the STM sensortile.box. I’ve never encountered this type of connector before. How to safely disconnect this type of connector?

Lift straight up.  Slide a thin screwdriver blade underneath the end of the connector where the conductors exit.  Lift gently.  Be sure that your screwdriver blade is between the bottom of the connector and the top of the removable portion.  Do NOT just pull up the end with the conductors - you will damage the connector.

Thank you!! It drove me crazy @DwayneReid


What battery connector is this

That is Molex EZmate (my site).

and how to disconnect?

It's just snapped in place. Lift it straight up. A small tool (spudger) to pry it helps.
